Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting between 2 or more cells
I'm trying to use conditional formatting to display a color in one cell if the value there is less than, between or equal to or greater than the values in two other cells.
I have tried using the regular functions and custom functions to no avail. I understand that I need a $[cell ID] to say I want the value from a specific cell, however I'm not sure if the problem is that the cells I want to reference are all formulas. Yet, if I do =[Cell 1]>[Cell 2], I get the proper boolean answer which tells me it can process the value of a formula.

In the picture, I want B14 to have a fill based on its value compared to I12 and I14 all 3 values will change depending on inputs so using a fixed comparison doesn't work for my needs.
Thanks in advance for your help.
In case the image didn't embed https://imgur.com/a/WxHc03B

You need to prepend = to your custom formula
=$B14<$I12

OR use the available format rule Less than instead of Custom formula
